# How to implement not with if statement in Ember Handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a statement like this:

```
{{#if IsValid}}
```

I want to know how I can use a negative `if` statement that would look like that:

```
{{#if not IsValid}}
```

Answer (score 504, accepted):

Simple answers for simple questions:

```
{{#unless isValid}}
{{/unless}}
```

Also keep in mind that you can insert an `{{else}}` in between an `{{#if}}` or `{{#unless}}` and the closing tag.

Comment: Thanks, I think that they should named it {{#ifnot flag}} instead of {{#unless flag}}.

Comment: @FabioCaccamo The original implementor(s) were/are Rubyist(s), where `unless` is a fairly common inversion of `if`.

Answer (score 57):

You have many ways of doing that.

## 1. Use `{{unless}}`:

```
{{#unless isValid}}
  ...
{{else}}
  ...
{{/unless}}
```

## 2. Use inline-if helper:

```
{{#if (if isValid false true)}}
  ...
{{else}}
  ...
{{/if}}
```

## 3. Use [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) addon:

```
{{#if (not isValid)}}
  ...
{{else}}
  ...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Found quite useful to use in next way: {{input type="text"  ... disabled=(not someProperty) ...}}

Answer (score 9):

it can be done in multiple ways.

1 use `unless`

```
{{#unless IsValid}}
<Your Code>
{{/unless}}
```

2.use `if else`

```
{{#if IsValid}}
{{else}}
<Your Code>
{{/if}}
```

3.use `not` helper

```
{{#if (not IsValid)}}
<Your Code>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 3):

**`unless` block helper** (built-in helper)

`unless` helper is the inverse of the `if` helper.

> Its block will be rendered if the expression returns a falsy value.

```
  {{#unless valid}}
  <h3 class="warning">WARNING</h3>
  {{/unless}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{#if items.length}}
    //Render
{{/if}}
```

Here items.length ..
          if it returns some value except null, then only it will enters into the if loop.

NOTE : You can check Boolean values also. In If block

```
{{#if booleanFloag}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Statements Will help full if you want to use if and else :

```
{{#if author}}
    <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
{{else}}
    <h1>Unknown Author</h1>
{{/if}}
```

NOTE : Dont close the if Block until logic finished ...