# How to implement ifCond not in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have a statement like below,

```
{{#ifCond IsTrue}}
```

how can i use ifCond statement with not like below,

```
{{#ifCond not IsTrue}}
```

Comment: have you looked at the unless block helper? basically an if not helper

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement not with if statement in ember handlebar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540176/how-to-implement-not-with-if-statement-in-ember-handlebar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an else statement:

```
{{#ifCond a b}}
  {{!-- a is equal to b. --}}
{{else}}
   {{!-- a is not equal to b --}}
{{/ifCond}}
```